# Is it possible to skip calling __set from class internal code

Tags: php

I wrote the __set in order to make sure something is done before setter anything

```
public function __setter($name, $value) {
    if ($this->needDoSomething) {$this->doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything();}
    $this->needDoSomething = false;
    $this->$name = $value;
}
```

However, the magic method will impact performance. In the same class, I have another function

```
private function loadData() {
    if ($this->needDoSomething) {$this->doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything();}
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Since the doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything() is already called, I don't need to call __set, but would like to set the property directly. This will largely help on performance.
However, I cannot remove the __set, because there are lot's of legacy code outside the class, and I need it to make the logic correct.

Seems with PHP I cannot add or remove methods to object on the fly. Any ideas?

Edit: The performance is caused by __set itself, because I have large number of objects and each have large number of properties to set. The code below shows __set is 6 times slower than set properties directly.

```
class Test {}
class Test2 {
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

function runOnObject($o) {
    $t = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $prop = "prop{$i}";
        $o->$prop = $i;
    }
    echo "".(microtime(true) - $t)." second ";
}

echo runOnObject(new Test()). "(With out __set)<p>";
echo runOnObject(new Test2()). "(With __set)";
```

The result:
0.084139823913574 second (With out __set)
0.47258400917053 second (With __set)

Comment: Do you have any **real** performance issues? Your question is really unclear. What actually are you in stuck with? If you need to run `$this->doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything();` - do it. Otherwise it's not obvious how the `loadData()` implementation is supposed to work correctly.

Comment: __set takes more time than set property directly, thus I only want the  code outside (which I cannot control) the class to use __set, but inside the class to set property directly. I do have a real performance issue, because the loadData() function will set lot's of properties. Skip __set for class internal code will solve the issue.

Comment: but `__set()` and `loadData()` do the different job. The first one performs `doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything` multiple times and the latter runs it just once.

Comment: Ok, I updated. The doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything is fake code, just demo that I need to do something before set properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a __get, you can store the properties in a private data structure (eg. an array), allowing direct access to the data from within the class, while still maintaining the same public interface.

Like this:

```
class Container
{
    private $properties = array();

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->doSomethingExpensive();
        $this->properties[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (!isset($this->properties[$key])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid Property ' . $key);
        }
        return $this->properties[$key];
    }

    public function loadData($data)
    {
        $this->doSomethingExpensive();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->properties[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    private function doSomethingExpensive()
    {
        echo 'Doing Work...' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Example

$c = new Container();
$c->loadData(array(
    'alpha' => 'A',
    'beta' => 'D',
    'charlie' => 'C',
    'delta' => 'D'
));

var_dump($c->alpha, $c->beta);
```

If this will be any faster, I don't know, it depends on your specific use case as you avoid running the "expensive" code repeatedly, but there will be some overhead from using __get.

Comment: the doSomething function itself is not expensive, the __set (been called hundreds of thousands times) is expensive.

Comment: Well, this avoids that as well. `loadData` is simply setting values in an array, without the overhead of the `__set` or the `doSomething` function calls.

Comment: but it introduce the __get call, which might be bigger than __set

Comment: "might be"? Yes, it might be. It does depend on your use case, as I said. If you were calling set 1000s of times, but get only 10, it will probably be an improvement, the inverse will of course be worse. You probably need to try it and profile your code.

Also, if you're calling __set "hundreds of thousands of times", you may want to consider a more efficient strategy in general.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not exactly what you want, but another thought... Use [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) for the dynamic set functionality instead of `__set`. Though you'll have to update the 'tons' of client code (not sure how unrealistic that may be).

```
<?php
class A implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $_doThings = false;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->loadData();
    }

    public function offsetExists($k) { return isset($this->$k); }
    public function offsetGet($k) { return $this->$k; }
    public function offsetUnset($k) { unset($this->$k); }
    public function offsetSet($k, $v) {
        if($this->_doThings)
            $this->doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything();
        $this->$k = $v;
    }

    private function doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything() {
        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function loadData() {
        $this->doSomeThingNecessaryBeforeSetAnything();
        $this->_doThings = false;
        foreach (array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3) as $key=>$value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo code**

```
$a = new A();
// Need to change all calls like $a->c = 4 to $a['c'] = 4
$a['c'] = 4;
var_dump($a);
```

So there's a painful code change required, but you get the best of both worlds. The dynamic behavior, and the performance.